# Properly making requests to a 3rd party API with Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, rest, laravel, oop

There are several questions on here that are *similar*, but not that are really providing exactly what I need.

I am creating a simple pet project in Laravel 5.3 that uses https://xboxapi.com/ to pull in JSON of Xbox Games.  At first I was going to create a Game model, but I understand that because I am using 3rd party, I really won't be pulling any data in from my own DB and there's really no need to use Eloquent ORM at this time.

What is the "Laravel way" to do this? I can use Guzzle to hit the API, and create methods to get game by title, get game by publisher, etc.  I guess what I am asking is where does this go within my app's file structure?  I understand there may be no right or wrong answer.  Really just looking for some insight into improving my OOP concepts.

***Edit***

Should I just put this into a GamesController? I don't want to have Guzzle in my controller, right?

Or should I actually create a Game class that extends the Eloquent model, and then overwrite methods like ::all() and ::find() to hit the API rather than the applications database?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use Guzzle. The `PSR-7` spec has implemented 3 `RFC`'s that dictate how HTTP request objects should be handled.

Guzzle does have PSR-7 support, you can see the [git repository here](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7).

For API based CRUD requests, create a new Controller namespace and move your API logic there. Consume your own API's internally if you need through these external end points:

```
artisan make:controller Api\\UserController
```

Now update your `RouteServiceProvider`, and add a new declaration:

```
private $api_namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Api`.
```

Now update your `mapApiRoutes()` and change your namespace:

```
'namespace' => $this->api_namespace
```

Now all of your API requests should route to `Api\Controllers`.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I am going to clarify my question, but since you just responded:  Would I just make these requests in the GamesController? Should I create a special class to hit the API?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not following your answer.  Here's what I am thinking: 

1) Create GamesController with typical CRUD methods. Let's start with a route of show() method on '/games/{game_title}

2) Within GamesController, show( $game_title ) and then use Guzzle to make the request with $game_title in the query

Comment: I am just not sure if it is bad practice to use Guzzle in my GamesController.  I feel like there should be a layer of abstraction there.

Comment: @plushyObject Sure. If you want to put an `interface` in front of Guzzle so you can exchange Guzzle out int he future that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I am going to put something together and share it to see what you think.

Comment: I think this should all be done in the Model layer.  Not in Controller.

Comment: What you decide to do depends on the patterns you follow which all have their pro's and con's. Generally though, controllers and models should be as light weight as possible and things like API communication should go in a service or even a repository class if it's for storing things.